# Getting access to a custom Master page from a user control

Tags: asp.net

We have created a Master page that inherits off the asp.net Master class.
We have also got ui controls that inherit off the standard asp.net ui control class.
Our Master page has a public member variable. We need to be able to access that member variable from the ui controls that we use.
However we can't seem to get at it? Is it our architecture that is wrong? Or the idea itself - user control getting acces to Master page variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is probably not a great design pattern. However, you should be able to do something like this:

```
MyMasterType myMaster = this.Page.Master as MyMasterType;
if (myMaster != null)
{
    myMaster.PublicProperty = value;
}
```

Comment: Yeh this is what we're going currently but it just feels wrong. So we're going to change the control to have a public property. The containing page will inject the value into that property when loading.

Comment: Is there a reason why injecting the value is better than grabbing it from the user control? I was already injecting and was looking for a way to grab it instead, but would gladly reconsider if there was good reason to.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons: 1) Using a property on the master page allows you to set the value in other contexts (future needs) and 2) The architecture is no longer tightly coupled. If the master page grabs the data, then the master page is dependent upon the user control being there.

Comment: I was thinking more of the the UserControl grabbing the Master page's property.

Comment: Ideally the Master page and UserControl would be completely standalone so as to promote code reuse and loose coupling.  The intermediate page using the Master page and house inthe user control should do the work setting the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

from: [Accessing masterpage properties from child pages in ASP.net VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182481/accessing-masterpage-properties-from-child-pages-in-asp-net-vb)

Comment: This is the other way...getting access to a control from the MasterPage. I need to get access to the MasterPage from the control.

Comment: Gotcha, not the best design pattern, like @etc said.